# Troubles installing LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

I'm trying to install a LAMP stack on my machine so 
I can eventually install wordpress. I'm following this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04). I've just finished following the instructions to install apache, and everything seemed to go great, but when I go to my IP address in the browser to see the default Apache web page, I'm getting an error that says:

```
This site can’t be reached
24.143.96.20 took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I feel I'm missing some vital piece of information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have also tried just using this command:

    sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

And I still have the same problem.

Comment: Oh snap! If I put "localhost" into the browser, the default apache page comes up, but if I put my IP address, it times out. Shouldn't this work with my IP address?

Comment: It depends where (in a network sense) you are testing it from, and how you have configured your network (router port forwarding settings, and/or the router's ability to perform NAT loopback may be factors)